Match and list values based on values listed in another column



0
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M




1
Products

Shop

2023-S
2023-M

2024-S
2024-M






2












lookup_array


3
Product A

Shop3

80
2%

120
22%



2024-S


4
Product B

Shop1

320
17%

400
15%



return_array


5
Product B

Shop3

90
30%

750
8%



2024-M


6
Product B

Shop2

500
4%

70
4%






7















8







400


selected data




9
Product C

Shop2

160
10%

245
10%

400

Product B


10
Product D

Shop1

500
8%

130
4%

400

Product E


11
Product D

Shop4

130
11%

130
4%

70

Product B


12
Product E

Shop2

75
8%

650
15%

520

Product H


13
Product E

Shop1

60
47%

90
7%

130

Product D


14
Product E

Shop4

500
25%

400
35%

90

Product E


15










130

Product D


16







70


130

Product F


17










70

Product H


18
Product E

Shop3

350
9%

140
13%






19
Product F

Shop2

60
30%

130
9%






20
Product G

Shop2

90
5%

370
12%






21
Product H

Shop1

390
27%

70
16%






22
Product H

Shop2

70
18%

520
42%








In Range M9:M17 I want to get the corresponding data based on the values in Range K9:17. 
This works both when applying the solutions from this question and this question:
Option 1 (Without flexible return_array) 
=LET(
     _Data, A3:I22,
     _Col, XLOOKUP(M3,A1:I1,_Data,""),
     _SelectedData, K9:K17,
     _Fx, LAMBDA(r,s, MAP(r,LAMBDA(c,COUNTIF(s:c,c)/10+c))),
     TOCOL(IF(_Fx(_Col,TAKE(_Col,1))=TOROW(_Fx(_SelectedData,
    TAKE(_SelectedData,1))),TAKE(_Data,,1),NA()),3,1))

Option 2 (With flexible return_array --> Cell M3) 
=IFERROR(LET(
     a, K9:K17,
     b, A1:I1,
     c, A3:I22,
     d, XLOOKUP(M3,b,c,""),
     MAP(a,LAMBDA(e, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(d=e,c),M6=b),3),
     COUNTIF(K9:e,e)-1)))),"")


However, as you can see in my data table above it can happen that there are empty rows in between the data which contain values (Cell H8 and Cell H16) that are also listed in Range K9:K17. 
In this case both formulas mentioned above return a 0 in between the list in Range M9:M17. 
In order to avoid this issue there must be somehow a condition added to the formula which says that all rows which do not have value in Column A should be ignored.
Do you know how to modify the formula to get the expected outcome?

Untested: Have you tried naming the result calculation res and use IF(res="","",res) ?

Quick fix to the existing formula (I believe ultimately you would need flexible return_array) :


=LET(
     _A, K6:K14,
     _B, A1:I1,
     _C, A3:I22,
     _D, XLOOKUP(M3,_B,_C,""),
     MAP(_A,LAMBDA(α, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(_D=α,IF(_C=0,x,_C)),M5=_B),3),
     COUNTIF(K6:α,α)-1))))



Actually, I apply both formulas in my original file. If you also have a solution for the other option it would be great.

In Option 2, could you try changing
MAP(a, LAMBDA(e, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(d = e, c), M6 = b), 3),
COUNTIF(K9:e, e) - 1)))

to
MAP(a, LAMBDA(e, @DROP(TOCOL(FILTER(IFS(d = e, 
IF(LEN(TRIM(c)) = 0, NA(), c)), 
M6 = b), 3), COUNTIF(K9:e, e) - 1)))

as TOCOL with option 3 omits cells with errors.
adopting earlier answer:
=LAMBDA(selected_data, data_range, col_headers, header_for_lookup, header_for_return,
    LET(
        lookup_col_0, INDEX(data_range, , XMATCH(header_for_lookup, col_headers)),
        return_col_0, INDEX(data_range, , XMATCH(header_for_return, col_headers)),
        comment_0, "remove cells with corressponding empty cells in return col",
        lookup_col, FILTER(lookup_col_0, LEN(TRIM(return_col_0)) > 0),
        return_col, FILTER(return_col_0, LEN(TRIM(return_col_0)) > 0),
        freq, LAMBDA(arr,
            LET(
                indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(arr)),
                MAP(indices, LAMBDA(i, SUM(IF(TAKE(arr, i) = INDEX(arr, i, ), 1, 0))))
            )
        ),
        comment_1, "400 1, 400 2",
        lookup_col_with_freq, lookup_col & " " & freq(lookup_col),
        selected_col_with_freq, selected_data & " " & freq(selected_data),
        xlook, XLOOKUP(selected_col_with_freq, lookup_col_with_freq, return_col),
        formatted, IF(RIGHT(header_for_return, 2) = "-M", TEXT(xlook, "0%"), xlook),
        formatted
    )
)(K9:K17, A3:I22, A1:I1, M3, M6)



Match Multiple Occurrences of Data

I don't think the formula can be easily fixed. Anyway, here's an alternative.
The GetRunningCount LAMBDA function returns a running count of a given (unsorted) column (array).

=LET(headers,A1:I1,data,A3:I22,lookup,K9:K22,
        lookup_header,M3,return_header,M5,
    GetRunningCount,LAMBDA(array,LET(
        so,SORT(HSTACK(SEQUENCE(ROWS(array)),array),2),
        d,DROP(so,,1),        
        SORTBY(SCAN(0,d=VSTACK("",DROP(d,-1)),LAMBDA(sr,r,
            IF(r,sr+1,1))),TAKE(so,,1)))),
    d,IF(data="","",data),
    rci,XLOOKUP(return_header,headers,d),
    f,rci<>"",
    rc,FILTER(rci,f),
    lc,FILTER(XLOOKUP(lookup_header,headers,d),f),
    src,GetRunningCount(lc),
    drc,GetRunningCount(lookup),
    r,BYROW(SEQUENCE(ROWS(drc)),LAMBDA(r,
        XLOOKUP(1,(lc=INDEX(lookup,r))
            *(src=INDEX(drc,r)),rc,""))),
    r)


Replace the last r with any other variable to see what it holds.
Note that the r in BYROW is a different variable.



Mainly change @DROP(FILTER(), Count-1) to index(FILTER(), COUNT, 1) in this answer: XLOOKUP with flexible column for return_array and not unique values in lookup_array
=LET(
    included, A3:A22 <> "",
    lookup_array, FILTER(XLOOKUP(M3, A1:I1, A3:I22, ""), included, ""),
    return_array, FILTER(XLOOKUP(M5, A1:I1, A3:I22, ""), included, ""),
    selected, K9:K17,
    BYROW(
        selected,
        LAMBDA(row,
            LET(
                filtered, FILTER(return_array, lookup_array = row, ""),
                current_count, COUNTIF(K9:row, row),
                INDEX(filtered, current_count, 1)
            )
        )
    )
)


